# How to parse xml that is supported in Android 4.0?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have used code from link for parsing xml it worked in versions less than android 2.3 but I am trying to get it done 4.0.3 it doesn't return any value in it at all.How solve this issue.I dont get any errors in the log but I dont get the parsed values as output.Here is the [link I used as code](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/)

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml) {

    Document doc = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return doc;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Log.e()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) instead of `System.out.println()`. You are probably getting an exception, but it isn't shown.

```java
try {
    ...
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "XML parse error", e);
    return null;
} catch (SAXException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Wrong XML file structure", e);
    return null;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "I/O exeption", e);
    return null;
}
```

(where `TAG` is a string-constant)

Comment: Nope its the same,it didnt do anything in catch part.

Comment: Then I don't know. [`DocumentBuilder.parse()`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/xerces/jaxp/DocumentBuilderImpl.java.html) should never return `null`. (Assuming Xerces is the implementation used. Check which implementation is used with `db.getClass().getName()`. )